# How to create a calculated column " Flag" using KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer, adx, askql

| timestamp | identifier | EDD | ward |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-04T09:00:00Z | ab1 | 2022-03-06T09:00:00Z | h1 |
| 2022-03-04T11:45:00Z | ab1 | 2022-03-07T09:00:00Z | h1 |
| 2022-03-05T11:45:00Z | ab1 | 2022-03-09T09:00:00Z | h1 |
| 2022-03-06T11:45:00Z | ab1 | 2022-03-09T09:00:00Z | G1 |
| 2022-03-04T11:45:00Z | xy | 2022-03-09T09:00:00Z | A1 |
| 2022-03-04T09:00:00Z | bc | 2022-03-07T09:00:00Z | S1 |
| 2022-03-06T11:45:00Z | abc | 2022-03-14T09:00:00Z | G1 |
| 2022-03-05T09:00:00Z | bc | 2022-03-12T09:00:00Z | S1 |
| 2022-03-07T11:45:00Z | xyz | 2022-03-10T09:00:00Z | Z1 |
| 2022-03-04T11:45:00Z | def | 2022-03-09T09:00:00Z | A1 |
| 2022-03-06T11:45:00Z | def | 2022-03-09T09:00:00Z | R1 |
| 2022-03-07T11:45:00Z | def | 2022-03-09T09:00:00Z | H1 |

For Every change in EDD for an identifier, it should flag 1

Expected output:

| timestamp | identifier | EDD | ward | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-04T09:00:00Z | ab1 | 2022-03-06T09:00:00Z | h1 |  |
| 2022-03-04T11:45:00Z | ab1 | 2022-03-07T09:00:00Z | h1 | 1 |
| 2022-03-05T11:45:00Z | ab1 | 2022-03-09T09:00:00Z | h1 | 1 |
| 2022-03-06T11:45:00Z | ab1 | 2022-03-09T09:00:00Z | G1 |  |
| 2022-03-04T11:45:00Z | xy | 2022-03-09T09:00:00Z | A1 |  |
| 2022-03-04T09:00:00Z | bc | 2022-03-07T09:00:00Z | S1 |  |
| 2022-03-06T11:45:00Z | abc | 2022-03-14T09:00:00Z | G1 |  |
| 2022-03-05T09:00:00Z | bc | 2022-03-12T09:00:00Z | S1 | 1 |
| 2022-03-07T11:45:00Z | xyz | 2022-03-10T09:00:00Z | Z1 |  |
| 2022-03-04T11:45:00Z | def | 2022-03-09T09:00:00Z | A1 |  |
| 2022-03-06T11:45:00Z | def | 2022-03-09T09:00:00Z | R1 |  |
| 2022-03-07T11:45:00Z | def | 2022-03-09T09:00:00Z | H1 |  |

Comment: Can you provide the sample and the output as datatable()?

Comment: Hello Avnera, sure

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, why was the OP answer deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [prev()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/prevfunction) function:

```
<Your query>
| extend Flag = iff(EOD != prev(EOD), 1, 0)
```

Just note that in order for `prev()` to work, the input to the `extend` operator should be [serialized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/windowsfunctions#serialized-row-set), for eample, sorted by values in some column. This is because records in Kusto are not ordered.